# Chrome Javascript console is not outputting function console.log, why?

Tags: javascript, console

I'm new to javascript and following a simple exercise from a course but for some reason my console isn't behaving as my tutorial suggests it should.

Any ideas why console.log is not being outputted when the function fizzBuzz is run? Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot of console and source]

Comment: See the play button labelled ⌘+Enter? You need to use it to run your snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared and implemented fizzBuzz.

Now, you will have to "call" (run/execute) your function.  To execute a function in JavaScript use ().

```
// Implement Function
function fizzBuzz() {
  number.push(count);
  count++;
  console.log(number);
}

// Call Function
fizzBuzz();
```